# What resolutions should iOS graphics be?

Tags: iphone, xcode, graphics, ios4

What pixels per inch settings do iOS 4 graphics need to be to support the high resolution display? Should I just use the standard 72, or should I specifically make images that are 320x480@163ppi and 640x960@326ppi? Or, should I just make images those dimensions and not worry about the resolution (i.e. leave it at the default 72)?

I'm not concerned about the iPad, only iPhone 3/GS, iPhone 4 and iPod Touch users.

***Note***
I realize this isn't about code, per se, but it is related to programming in so much as this is necessary for me to finish my iOS application ;)

Comment: PPI is irrelevant outside the world of printing. Just follow the guidelines on size and naming conventions that apple lists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Icon and image sizes are documented at https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/custom-icons/

Answer (score 0):

326 ppi as that is the resolution of the retina display. They will resize/resample automatically on lower resolution displays.

Here is some more guidance:

http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/preparing-your-iphone-app-for-higher-resolutions/